# Redshift JSON Parsing

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I have some JSON data in Redshift table of type character varying. An example entry is:

```
[{"value":["*"], "key":"testData"}, {"value":"["GGG"], key: "differentData"}]
```

I want to return vales based on keys, how can i do this? I'm attempting to do something like

`json_extract_path_text(column, 'value')` but unfortunately it errors out. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "based on keys"? The proper path for the value elements would be `[*].value`. Assuming this is JSONPath - https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @OneCricketeer Switched the query to `json_extract_path_text(column, '[*].value')`, and still nothing is returned

Comment: I don't know how these functions work, but looking at the documentation, you might want either `json_extract_array_element_text` or `json_parse` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first issue is that your string isn't valid JSON.  There are mismatched and missing quotes.  I think you mean:

```
[{"value":["*"], "key":"testData"}, {"value":["GGG"], "key": "differentData"}]
```

I don't know if this is a data issue or a transcription error but these functions won't work unless the json text is valid.

The next thing to consider is that at the top level this json is an array so you will need to use json_extract_array_element_text() function to pick up an element of the array.  For example:

```
json_extract_array_element_text('json string', 0)
```

So putting this together we can extract the first "value" with (untested):

```
json_extract_path_text(
  json_extract_array_element_text(
    '[{"value":["*"], "key":"testData"}, {"value":["GGG"], "key": "differentData"}]', 0
  ), 'value'
)
```

Should return the string ["*"].